# How to configure separate transaction threshold for each application in AppDynamics controller?

Tags: java, profiling, appdynamics

I am having multiple java application configured in my app-dynamics controller and they have their own java agent running and reporting the metrics.

My problem is that SLA for each application is different and if i change the slow transaction threshold for a single application. it changes it for other application as well, which is creating lot of trouble for me.

**So my question is how to configure separate transaction threshold for each application in AppDynamics controller** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build multiple baselines within AppDynamics if you'd like to. The thresholds should be auto calculated off deviation from baseline. This makes it so you don't need to configure them manually. If you want to do SLA tracking, Business iQ (analytics) can do this very well. We also are building additional features around SLA use cases we can share.

Feel free to email me or support for a hand.